# Getting NaN values when normalizing group in dataframe using GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in the form of the following:

```
user_ID song_ID listens
------- ------ -------
  U0     S1      14
  U0     S2      4
  U1     S3      23
  U1     S4      10
```

I want to normalize across users so I tried:

```
grouped = df['listens'].groupby(df['user_ID'])
min_max = lambda x: (5-1)*((x - x.min()) / (x.max()-x.min())) + 1
df['normal_L'] = grouped.transform(min_max)
```

For the most part it works! What goes wrong is that it also tried to normalize the user ID. How I know this, is that the NaN values that I'm getting are at the intervals which the next user's history starts. So something like this...

```
user_Id song_ID listens normal_L
------- ------ ------- --------
  U0     S1      14      5
  U0     S2      4       3
  U1     S3      23      NaN
  U1     S4      10      5
```

I'm confused as to how to fix this since the logic makes sense i.e. you group the listens by user. For each listen, you perform min-max normalization and then you save it into the original data frame.

Comment: First, your example is inconsistent (`UserId` vs `user_ID`, `values` vs `Normal_L`, etc.) Please edit it. Second, I applied your function to your data and got a correct result (`5 1 5 1`, not `5 3 NaN 5`). You may want to double check your example. As for the NaNs, you must be getting them when `x.max()==xmin()`, in which case your `min_max` is undefined. You must decide for yourself what is the rank of songs if all of them have the same value of `Listens`.

Comment: I fixed the inconsistencies, thank you. The data was just an example off the top of my head to show what is happening, so you're right the NaNs are probably happening when the values for 'listens' are uniform, that is x.max()==x.min(). I will have to put a condition in to check for that.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a more straightforward approach to me:

`df['normal_L'] = df.groupby('user_ID')['listens'].apply(min_max)`

- Less (and clearer) code
- It very clearly does not operate on the user_ID column, which you suspect is causing you problems.
- like [DYZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4492932/dyz) said you should explicitly handle the case where x.min() == x.max() if you're not OK with nulls.